# What to do to let TextView increase its height

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-constraintlayout

I have the following layout and my problem here is that `TextView`only shows 3 lines and no more even for a longer text.

What's my mistake here please?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btStartItem"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbTestItem"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:paddingStart="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
            android:progressBackgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:progressTint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
            android:scaleY="5"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingStart="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
            android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btStartItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:text="@string/action_start"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivStatusItem"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivStatusItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/status_test"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:maxHeight="40dp"
        android:maxWidth="40dp"
        android:src="@drawable/question"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btStartItem"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried "android: singleline=false"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To let TextView show everything it has just change android:layout_width of FrameLayout from 0dp to wrap_content:

```
(...)
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btStartItem"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="40"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbTestItem"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:progressTint="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:scaleY="5"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingStart="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btStartItem"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:text="@string/action_start"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="30"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ivStatusItem"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/frameLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivStatusItem"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="30"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:maxHeight="40dp"
    android:maxWidth="40dp"
    android:src="@drawable/question"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btStartItem"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Try to set [maxlines Attribute](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3AmaxLines) to the `TextView`.

Like:

```
android:maxLines="10"
```

Comment: This won't work since TextView's height is set from parent dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Change FrameLayout height from **0dp** to **wrap_content**

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btStartItem"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

to

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btStartItem"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```